# iPhone - UIImagePickerController -> save the image to app folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an iPhone application using a `UIImagePickerController`. As `sourceType` I have

- UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary
- UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera
- UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum

so the user can make a photo or select one from the photo library from the photos or camera photos.

The image will be displayed in a UIImageView. The image should be saved if the user closes the app. So for text fields, I use `NSUserDefaults`. I know, it is not a good way to save the image inside the NSUSerDefaults with NSData, so I want to save / copy the image to a folder which is controlled by my application similar to the NSUserDefaults.

How can I do this? I want to save it, and then I can write the path to the file into my `NSUserDefaults` and read it on startup of the application.

Thank you in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the following code in `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` delegate implementation

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    //obtaining saving path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"latest_photo.png"];

    //extracting image from the picker and saving it
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];   
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
        UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(editedImage);
        [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

**UPD**

Swift 3.0 code by [XueYu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3608824/xueyu)

> here the image is saved as jpeg but you can also save it as png. the
>   0.0 parameter stands for compression and it's the lowest quality, if you want to get the best use 1.0.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    //obtaining saving path
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    let imagePath = documentsPath?.appendingPathComponent("image.jpg")

    // extract image from the picker and save it
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        try! UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.0)?.write(to: imagePath!)
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```

Comment: I had to use [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; instead of UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage

Comment: Exactly, it depends you allowed editing or not, picker.allowsEditing = YES;

Comment: This assumes the image is a png (or is at least irreverent about saving the image as a png).

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the file format you want to save, you can use

```m
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

OR

```m
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the code to save the UIImage into the document directory. You can use this code in didFinishPickingImage delegate method:

```
// Create paths to output images
NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory();
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"];
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory();
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.jpg"];

// Write a UIImage to JPEG with minimum compression (best quality)
// The value 'image' must be a UIImage object
// The value '1.0' represents image compression quality as value from 0.0 to 1.0
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];

// Write image to PNG
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];

// Let's check to see if files were successfully written...

// Create file manager
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Point to Document directory
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory();
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

// Write out the contents of home directory to console
NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
```

> EDIT

You can also use:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

to find the path to your application document directory, instead of NSHomeDierctory.

Comment: @iHS i've the requirment of retrieve images from api and store it in application..can i use the same code to save images??

Answer (score 2):

Update knuku's answer for Swift 3.0

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    //obtaining saving path
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    let imagePath = documentsPath?.appendingPathComponent("image.jpg")

    // extract image from the picker and save it
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        try! UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.0)?.write(to: imagePath!)
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```

here the image is saved as jpeg but you can also save it as png. the 0.0 parameter stands for compression and it's the lowest quality, if you want to get the best use 1.0.