# Getting URL of UIImage selected from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, nsurl

I'm trying to provide a user selection of an image from Photo Library. Thus I'm using `UIImagePickerController` for selecting. But here comes an issue with getting its initial URL in the file system (I need this for `CKAsset`).

My code.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as NSURL
    let path = imageURL.path!
    let imageName = path.lastPathComponent
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectory = paths.first as String!
    let localPath = documentDirectory + "/" + imageName

    let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: localPath)!
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)!

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

**imageURL** is kinda cryptic. It describes Asset URL, but not one in File System. And it looks like: `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=B6C0A21C-07C3-493D-8B44-3BA4C9981C25&ext=JPG`.

According to this logic the **path** is `/asset.JPG` where `asset.JPG` is a name of the image.

Then I'm accessing my Documents folder and trying to find there a file with path:

> /Users/Eugene/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3C5E9A23-8220-4B37-BD14-F1E42EEC2C7C/data/Containers/Data/Application/20EBAAE2-6C6F-4651-A48F-16A222CCB3A2/Documents/asset.JPG

Cryptic as well but seems to be a real path for a not existing image... No image with that path can be found. And this makes me sick.

Do I have to save an image from the beginning? Or is there any other way to go?

I've looked through several tutorials using **AssetsLibrary** API but I didn't find anything useful to solve my problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Okay, I've solved the issue.

All you have to do is simply grab the image (`info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage`) and save to the given directory. If you need to save only 1 picture it works great. The code id below.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as NSURL
    let imageName = imageURL.path!.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as String
    let localPath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    data.writeToFile(localPath, atomically: true)

    let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: localPath)!
    let photoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath)
    let imageWithData = UIImage(data: imageData)!

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer for Swift 2? Thank you!

Comment: not working in Swift 3, I converted the code to make it compile but the path returned does not point to the selected image

Comment: for Swift 3, check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957972/iphone-uiimagepickercontroller-save-the-image-to-app-folder/43456006#43456006

Comment: @majorton what is the best way to save 100 images?

Answer (score 15):

In **SWIFT 4** you can try this:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    
    
    if let imgUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as? URL{
        let imgName = imgUrl.lastPathComponent
        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
        let localPath = documentDirectory?.appending(imgName)
        
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
        data.write(toFile: localPath!, atomically: true)
        //let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: localPath!)!
        let photoURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: localPath!)//NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath!)
        print(photoURL)
        
    }

    APPDEL.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For Swift 5+ ;according to @Jaydip answer

```
if let imgUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL{
        let imgName = imgUrl.lastPathComponent
        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
        let localPath = documentDirectory?.appending(imgName)

        let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        let data = image.pngData()! as NSData
        data.write(toFile: localPath!, atomically: true)
        //let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: localPath!)!
        let photoURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: localPath!)//NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath!)
        print(photoURL)

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
//this block of code grabs the path of the file   
let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as NSURL
let imagePath =  imageURL.path!
let localPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent(imagePath)

 //this block of code adds data to the above path
 let path = localPath.relativePath!
 let imageName = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
 let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageName)
 data?.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)

//this block grabs the NSURL so you can use it in CKASSET
 let photoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
 }
```

Comment: @Peter Kreinz, hope this one helps

Answer (score 2):

check this solution.

```
 import AssetsLibrary  

     func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
          self.imagePicker = picker
          if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            let controller = CropViewController(image: selectedImage )
            controller.delegate = self
            picker.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
          }

       else if let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL{
          let assetLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
          assetLibrary.assetForURL(imageUrl , resultBlock: { (asset: ALAsset!) -> Void in
            if let actualAsset = asset as ALAsset? {
              let assetRep: ALAssetRepresentation = actualAsset.defaultRepresentation()
              let iref = assetRep.fullResolutionImage().takeUnretainedValue()
              let image = UIImage(CGImage: iref)
              let controller = CropViewController(image: image)
              controller.delegate = self
              picker.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            }, failureBlock: { (error) -> Void in
          })
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

In swift 4

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {        
    if let imgUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL{

        let imgName = imgUrl.lastPathComponent
        let documentDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
        let localPath = documentDirectory.appending(imgName)

        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.3)! as NSData
        data.write(toFile: localPath, atomically: true)
        let photoURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: localPath)

    }

}
```

Comment: FYI - `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.referenceURL` is being deprecated as of iOS 11.0.

Answer (score 2):

## swift 4.2

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    
    //obtaining saving path
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    let imagePath = documentsPath?.appendingPathComponent("image.jpg")
    
    // extract image from the picker and save it
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        
        let imageData = pickedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)
        try! imageData?.write(to: imagePath!)
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
let imgUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.imageURL] as? URL
```

Comment: Simple solution but spot on! This works for me. Thanks.