# Getting URL of UIImage from UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsurl

I'm trying to get the URL of an image imported from Library in Swift to send it to Apple Watch with `transferFile(_:metadata)` but I'm having two error on `NSURL`.

This is my code:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
{
    imagePicked.image = image    
    let imageUrl = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
    let imageName = imageUrl.path!.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as String!
    let localPath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)
    let image = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as! UIImage
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    data!.writeToFile(localPath, atomically: true)

    let photoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

And I'm getting error with *imageName and *localPath because it says that:

> 'lastPathComponent' is unavailable: Use lastPathComponent on NSURL instead.
>   'stringByAppendingPathComponent' is unavailable: Use URLByAppendingPathComponent on NSURL instead.

But I can't get it right in Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The error messages are telling you what to do. And there's many examples on SO.

Comment: @EricD. I tried changing values to NSURL in code, but that doesn't work when testing the app.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apple has changed something in their `NSString` and `NSURL` library in their latest release (iOS 9), but those methods are available from iOS 4. You can check the related [Apple Forum Post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13580) for more details.

For fixing this error, you need to change the code like:

#### Swift 2:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
{
    let imageUrl          = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
    let imageName         = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as String!
    let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
    let localPath         = photoURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(imageName!)
    let image             = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as! UIImage
    let data              = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    data!.writeToFile(localPath.absoluteString, atomically: true)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

#### Swift 3:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
    let imageName         = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
    let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)
    let image             = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as! UIImage
    let data              = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    do
    {
        try data?.write(to: localPath!, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
    }
    catch
    {
        // Catch exception here and act accordingly
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

Reference:

1. [lastPathComponent](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/lastPathComponent)
2. [URLByAppendingPathComponent:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/URLByAppendingPathComponent:)

Comment: @zumzum: I've updated my answer for Swift 3. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @MayankJain: Did you check the Swift 3 version ? Can you tell me what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Swift 3 version return nil for UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL

Comment: @UmaAchanta Can you please show me the code in which you are getting that error ? If you are using the same code, I think the issue might be with some other part of your code base (Something like missing brackets)

Comment: thanks, @Midhun - Its compiled. the issue found in runtime is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521667/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-applications

Answer (score 5):

As of iOS 11, you can get the image URL from the info dictionary with the key **UIImagePickerControllerImageURL**.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as? URL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
   //this block of code grabs the path of the file   
   let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as NSURL
   let imagePath =  imageURL.path!
   let localPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent(imagePath)

  //this block of code adds data to the above path
   let path = localPath.relativePath!
   let imageName = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
   let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageName)
   data?.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)

  //this block grabs the NSURL so you can use it in CKASSET
   let photoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
}
```

Comment: Please don't copy and paste the same [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35530982/189134) to multiple questions. At the very least, you should explain how this solves *this* question and why it isn't simply a generic copy/paste.