# Swift, How to get the image path from UIPickerView in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

In Android there is a way to take the selected image path and display it in our app. Is there any way to do the same thing in iOS too? To select the image from the picker view, take the image path and display in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` returns only the image's data, with no reference to its local storage.

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

     if let localUrl = (info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] ?? info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]) as? NSURL {

        print (localUrl)
        //if you want to get the image name 
        let imageName = localUrl.path!.lastPathComponent
     }    
 }
```

for more help see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085409/getting-url-of-uiimage-from-uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: let localUrl = (info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] ?? info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]) as? NSURL

Comment: see this https://github.com/digipost/ios/blob/master/Digipost/UploadImageController.swift

Comment: Anbu - thanks for the link. Did I need to add anything in info.plist

Answer (score 1):

**Delegate callback** `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`. Simply obtain the path from the info dictionary's `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`.

[more check apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)

Answer (score 1):

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!)
{

 self.displayImg.image = image

    let imgURL: NSURL = editingInfo.valueForKey("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL") as! NSURL

    print(imgURL.absoluteString)

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```