# Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both/Applications

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Why am I getting this?

> objc[3993]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x112bb0910) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x1129da210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   2016-09-15 19:06:45.101896 Fly App[3993:92356] subsystem:
>   com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0,
>   persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2,
>   enable_private_data: 0 2016-09-15 19:06:45.108211 Fly App[3993:92356]
>   subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level:
>   0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2,
>   enable_private_data: 0 2016-09-15 19:06:45.118565 Fly App[3993:92353]
>   subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1,
>   persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0,
>   enable_private_data: 0 2016-09-15 19:06:45.153130 Fly App[3993:92250]
>   subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0,
>   persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2,
>   enable_private_data: 0 2016-09-15 19:06:45.537455 Fly App[3993:92250]
>   subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App,
>   enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0,
>   debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0,
>   privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0

Any reasons in particular? (It never happened before until today after updated xcode, and updated my project to swift 3)

Can someone please help?

*** Edited ***

I'm not convinced on the suggestions given by fellow developers so I've kept looking around for an answer. I've found a thread that says that the problem seems to have been cased by the Facebook SDK. However I haven't installed the Facebook SDK (Cocoapod) yet on my project, however I'm using the Import Social to share on Twitter, so I removed the Import Social and the ran my project again.

This time I didn't get the same Output on the debugger, I got this instead:

> 2016-09-16 11:57:41.393517 Fly App[1277:48009] subsystem:
>   com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0,
>   persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2,
>   enable_private_data: 0
>
> 2016-09-16 11:57:41.396355 Fly App[1277:48009] subsystem:
>   com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0,
>   persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2,
>   enable_private_data: 0
>
> 2016-09-16 11:57:41.411055 Fly App[1277:48006] subsystem:
>   com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1,
>   persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0,
>   enable_private_data: 0
>
> 2016-09-16 11:57:41.426085 Fly App[1277:47901] subsystem:
>   com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level:
>   0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0,
>   enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>
> 2016-09-16 11:57:41.946193 Fly App[1277:47901] subsystem:
>   com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1,
>   persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0,
>   generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0,
>   enable_private_data: 0

So the "Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both" is gone:

> objc[3993]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x112bb0910) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x1129da210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I still don't know what all this means. Has anyone found something to solve this issue?

Comment: It seems you have implemented in both application. 

Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x112bb0910) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x1129da210). One of the two will be used.

Did you try removing one?

Comment: I've been getting that message in one of my projects as well. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520499/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-frameworks) provided a good explanation. And like the author mentions, I don't think it's causing any problems, it's just annoying.

Comment: Resetting the iOS simulator fixed this for me. Simulator -> Reset Content And Settings.

Answer (score 10):

Its not a compiler warning, its an Objective-C runtime warning, and it is not in any code that you control. You can safely ignore it, as you cannot fix it.

Answer (score -1):

NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses photos