# How to solve this log when i update Xcode8？

Tags: ios, xcode

> Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x11aae8910) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x11a87b210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Its not an error, it just a warning.

Read the answer here,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39582284/6742121

It says it will not cause the problem.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is a warning: objc[3993]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x112bb0910)

**find the link** : [Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both/Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521667/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-applications)