# UIWebView not loading in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, payumoney

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: address];
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", webViewString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[_paymentWebView loadRequest: request];
```

I load the UIWebView but I got this error in my application when I try to access the **PayUMoney** payment gateway via `UIWebView` in above code but it show this error and I am using `AFNetworking` in other API calls.
Kindly help me to resolve this error.

> objc[4933]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x12487e998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x1246a3d38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.**

Comment: This error does not related to webview.

Comment: refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521667/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-applications

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: address];
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", webViewString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_paymentWebView loadRequest: request];
```

You don't need to use **setHTTPBody** or **setHTTPMethod**.

Comment: Thanks poles for your response. and where i pass the **body** string in the webview

Comment: what its actually contains?

Comment: If you wanna pass some parameter then you have to pass it with the url by appending.

Comment: you can pass in both ways either in body or as query parameter.query parameter is of limited size.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is not how we should load url in webview.

The sweet and simple way is as below to load URL in UIWebView.

```
NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:websiteUrl];
[myWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```