# Save image in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to pick image from device's Photo Library in method:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{

    userPhoto.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage?
    userPhoto.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    userPhoto.clipsToBounds = true

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and save this picture in Realm (as NSData):

```
asset.assetImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(userPhoto.image!)! as NSData?
```

...

```
   try! myRealm.write
        {
            user.assetsList.append(asset)
            myRealm.add(user)
        }
```

After build succeeded and trying to pick and save image (in the app) i have app error:
'Binary too big'

What i'm doing wrong?

P.S. Sorry for my English :)

---

After some actions i have this code. But it's overwrite my image.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
    let imageName = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let photoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
    let localPath = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as! UIImage
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    do
    {
        try data?.write(to: localPath!, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
    }
    catch
    {
        // Catch exception here and act accordingly
    }

    userPhoto.image = image
    userPhoto.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    userPhoto.clipsToBounds = true

    urlCatch = (localPath?.path)!
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
}
```

Comment: debug and print your imageName 
let imageName = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
if it's always the same name, the image gets overridden.
the image name must be unique. something like 
let timestampFilename = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)) + "_newImage.png"

Comment: It works great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't save the image itself into realm, just save the location of the image into realm as String or NSString and load the image from that saved path. Performance wise it's always better to load images from that physical location and your database doesn't get too big

```
  func loadImageFromPath(_ path: NSString) -> UIImage? {

        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path as String)

        if image == nil {
            return UIImage()
        } else{
            return image
        }
    }
```

or you just save the image name, if it's in your documents directory anyhow

```
func loadImageFromName(_ imgName: String) -> UIImage? {

        guard  imgName.characters.count > 0 else {
            print("ERROR: No image name")
            return UIImage()
        }

        let imgPath = Utils.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(imgName)
        let image = ImageUtils.loadImageFromPath(imgPath as NSString)           
        return image    
    }
```

and here a rough example how to save a captured image to your directory with a unique name:

```
    @IBAction func capture(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in

                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
                //self.stillImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                //self.savedImage.image = self.stillImage

                let timestampFilename = String(Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)) + "someName.png"

                let filenamePath =  URL(fileReferenceLiteralResourceName: getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(timestampFilename))
                let imgData = try! imageData?.write(to: filenamePath, options: [])

            })



    /* helper get Document Directory */
    class func getDocumentsDirectory() -> NSString {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        //print("Path: \(documentsDirectory)")
        return documentsDirectory as NSString
    }
```

Comment: Thx for answer! 
Save capture image - it means i have copy image from PhotoLibrary to image Directory of my app?

Can you tell me how i can get path(NSURL) of captured image in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method?

Comment: have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085409/getting-url-of-uiimage-from-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: 1. when i'm trying to save picture it's rewriting.

Comment: 2. when i'm restart my app (in simulator) - i have no images (been before)

Comment: what you mean with rewriting? overwriting? check if the image name is unique for every image
when you you use the simulator the images only lives in that specific simulator instance. if you reset the simulator, the images are gone. that's normal. on our phone they will stay in your app directoy

Comment: i have edit my question and add code what i have now. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 5):

https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#current-limitations 
maximum data size is 16 MB . this is limitation of realm

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your serializing the image data (for example if it's a lossless bitmap), it's quite possible that this data exceed 16MB, which as you've stated is Realm's maximum supported size for binary properties.

When you invoke NSData.length, how large does it say your data is?

Comment: you have to compress the image as individual NSData properties cannot exceed 16MB

Comment: if you are satisfied with my answer give it a right mark or make it as a answer, so it can help others. :)

Comment: How i can compress my NSData?
Or maybe i must to store path to file - how i can get path to the file?