# iOS:After I taken photo use my iphone camera,how to get the picture counter-ALAsset?

Tags: ios, camera, photo, alasset

As the title, after I taken a photo with my iphone camera, how can I get the `ALAsset`, which is the photo?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255789/getting-url-of-uiimage-selected-from-uiimagepickercontroller see this

Answer (score 0):

```
ALAssetsLibrary *al = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];


[al enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll

    usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
    {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
        {
            if (asset)
            {                
                 .. do something with the asset
            }
        }
        ];
    }

    failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
    {
        // User did not allow access to library
        .. handle error 
    }
 ];
```

Comment: ,thanks your reply,because I use camera to take a photo, how can I get that photo ? the first asset? or can I get the asset by lastly time? if can, how?

Comment: you are using imagepicker to capture photo?

Comment: Have you added this method ? - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info