# How to fetch Directory(localpath) using UIImagePickerControllerDelegate in Swift 3.1?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I going to fetch directory of photo From UIImagepicker using delegates method. but how to do this i don't know so give me hint for this isssue

Comment: Do you need path of your photos?

Comment: Yes @SourLeangChhean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting URL of UIImage selected from UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255789/getting-url-of-uiimage-selected-from-uiimagepickercontroller)

Comment: yes but that code not working m working on swift 3.1  and xcode 8.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line you can get the path of your photo in swift 3++:

```
let imageUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
```

You can use it in delegate function **func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])**

Code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    // get image url
    let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
    let imageName         = imageUrl?.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
    let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: localPath!.path) {
        do {
            try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)?.write(to: localPath!)
            print("file saved")
        }catch {
            print("error saving file")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("file already exists")
    }
}
```

Comment: i  knew that but i want proper answer

Comment: @Sagarvaishnav what do u mean "Proper answer"?

Comment: @Sagarvaishnav check it again.

Comment: wait i'll check it out

Comment: @SourLeangChhean which object give me  a path  of selected image ?

Comment: let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL