# UIImagePicker is returning nil for info[.imageURL], but works fine with info[.mediaURL]

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

So I have a UIImagepickerController and I am trying to get the URL of an image.

Here is my ImagePicker code:

```
class ImagePicker: UIImagePickerController {

init(mediaTypes: [String], allowsEditing: Bool) {
    super.init(navigationBarClass: .none, toolbarClass: .none)
    self.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
    self.allowsEditing = allowsEditing
    self.imageExportPreset = .current        
    self.sourceType = .photoLibrary    
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Here is how I call the image picker in the view controller:

```
    func presentImagePicker(type: [String]) {
    let picker = ImagePicker(mediaTypes: type, allowsEditing: true)
    picker.delegate = self
    present(picker, animated: true)
}
```

And:

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let imageURL = info[.imageURL] as? URL
    // This print statement returns nil.
    print("\(imageURL)")
}
```

It seems like it is working fine, but when I select my image in the image picker the imageURL returns nil and I don't know why.

Maybe this will also help, but when I switch the info[.imageURL] to info[.mediaURL] and change the image picker type to ["public.movie"] instead of ["public.image"], it works fine and the mediaURL does not return nil, but it returns a url.

So for some reason it will return a url for a movie, but it won't return a url for an image.

Comment: What if you print info[.imageURL] without casting it as a URL? Documentation says it is NSURL. See this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255789/getting-url-of-uiimage-selected-from-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: Check if it works before ios 13 ..

Comment: @Victor Engel I tried `print(info[.imageURL])` and it still returned nil :(

Comment: OK. Did you follow the link? It suggests something else to look at.