# received memory warning on multiple image click from camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8.1

am using Custom camera for clicking multiple images.now after clicking few images am getting received memory warning and my application isn crashing.Can anyone help me to resolve this.my code showed  below

```
CImage = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


[arrimages addObject: CImage];





if (aPicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
    custvw.cameraButton.enabled = YES;


}
else
{


    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {

        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
        {
            if (picker.sourceType==UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary)
            {

                [self.picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

            }

            else
            {





            }


        }
        else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
        {
        }
    }

            else
    {
        [self.picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


    }


    }
```

Comment: can you post what error do you get while crashing ?

Comment: am not getting am crash error in console its just showing the    Received memory warning. and application is crashing

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to hold the selected images in memory by adding them to an array. These images are in general very memory intensive and can easily fill up the memory.

```
[arrimages addObject: CImage];
```

Possible solution:

- Scale images

Scaling the images after retrieving them from the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate 
- imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: also helps reducing the memory footprint.

[How to adjust a image size after using UIImagePickerController take a photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756665/how-to-adjust-a-image-size-after-using-uiimagepickercontroller-take-a-photo)

- Save images to disk

Don't keep the images in memory, instead save them to the disk and get them from disk if needed.

[iPhone - UIImagePickerController -> save the image to app folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957972/iphone-uiimagepickercontroller-save-the-image-to-app-folder)